# Heroku serves a blank page after a successful build

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, web-deployment

I have a fullstack Vue application with Node and MongoDB. When I deploy it to Heroku using Heroku CLI everything builds fine but when I open the app it shows a blank page. I know there could be dozens of reasons, but I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong in the config files, either webpack or eslint, etc. Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

**From Heroku CLI**

```
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 862 bytes | 862.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  12.2.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 12.2.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.2.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.9.0
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        
remote:        > nodent-runtime@3.2.1 install /tmp/build_6acdcefd755fbf3c1b13db0b077c27aa/node_modules/nodent-runtime
remote:        > node build.js
remote:        
remote:        ## Built /tmp/build_6acdcefd755fbf3c1b13db0b077c27aa/node_modules/nodent-runtime/dist/index.js
remote:        
remote:        > yorkie@2.0.0 install /tmp/build_6acdcefd755fbf3c1b13db0b077c27aa/node_modules/yorkie
remote:        > node bin/install.js
remote:        
remote:        setting up Git hooks
remote:        can't find .git directory, skipping Git hooks installation
remote:        
remote:        > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_6acdcefd755fbf3c1b13db0b077c27aa/node_modules/ejs
remote:        > node ./postinstall.js
remote:        
remote:        added 962 packages from 1106 contributors and audited 36327 packages in 30.893s
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > tradish@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_6acdcefd755fbf3c1b13db0b077c27aa
remote:        > vue-cli-service build
remote:        
remote:        
remote: -  Building for production...
remote:         DONE  Compiled successfully in 3571ms10:38:53 PM
remote:        
remote:          File                                 Size               Gzipped
remote:        
remote:          dist/js/chunk-vendors.fc529923.js    23.70 KiB          8.65 KiB
remote:          dist/js/app.d6a75270.js              1.64 KiB           0.81 KiB
remote:        
remote:          Images and other types of assets omitted.
remote:        
remote:         DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
remote:         INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
remote:              
remote:        
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        
remote:        > yorkie@2.0.0 uninstall node_modules/yorkie
remote:        > node bin/uninstall.js
remote:        
remote:        husky
remote:        uninstalling Git hooks
remote:        done
remote:        
remote:        removed 962 packages and audited 5070 packages in 16.92s
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Static HTML app detected
remote:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
remote:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
remote: 100  838k  100  838k    0     0  15.1M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15.1M
remote: -----> Installed directory to /app/bin
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 48.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v18
remote:        https://tradish.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/tradish.git
13fbf2e..8aec533  master -> master
```

**Webpack**

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
 main: "./src/client/main.js"
},
mode: "production"
};
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
"root": true,
"extends": [
 // add more generic rulesets here, such as:
 "plugin:vue/base"
],
"rules": {
 "strict": 0,
 "semi": "error"
},
"parserOptions": {
 "parser": "babel-eslint",
 "ecmaVersion": 2018,
 "sourceType": "module",
 "ecmaFeatures": {
   "modules": true,
   "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
 }
}
}
```

**static.json**

```
{
"root": "dist",
"clean_urls": true,
"routes": {
 "/**": "index.html"
}
}
```

**folder structure**

```
dist
 js
 index.html
node_modules
public
src
 client
 server
config.js
.eslintrc.json
babel.config.js
package-lock.json
package.json
static.json
webpack.config.js
```

Comment: is `index.html` inside dist folder? can you share folder structure it will help.

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary yes, it's inside dist. I added folder structure, thanks!

Comment: Looks good! I am not able to figure out what the real problem is but what you can do   is add express and server your file from express route. This might solve your problem for now.

Comment: can you add browser console output?

Comment: @OleksandrVetoshkin the console is empty. No errors, no messages

Comment: 1) Please share your `App.vue`, `main.js` and `package.json`as well. Could be related to how your app is getting initialised.
2) This may sound dumb, but, does the app work locally? How are you running it locally? Are you using vue cli for local development?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this @Romaldowoho?